Permissions error when executing setserial command
I have recently transitioned from CentOS 7.9 to AlmaLinux 8.9, and I have noticed a permission error when executing the following command:
$ setserial /dev/ttyAP0 closing_wait none

I get the following output:
Cannot set serial info: Operation not permitted

My user account is part of the dialout group which I believe needs to be done when wanting to communicate to serial devices, but apart from this I am not sure what else could cause this error message.
When executing the following command, I can confirm I am part of the dialout group:
$ groups tester


If I list out my serial ports on my machine, I can see they are part of the dialout group.
$ ls -l /dev/ttyAP*


I don't run the command via sudo on either Linux Distro, so is there anyway I can identify the cause of the message in AlmaLinux.

Did you logout/login after you added yourself to the dialout group? Check with id. Did you verify that dialout is the right group and device with ls -l /devttyAP0

Hello @waltinator I have restarted my machine and checked for the correct permissions of my listed serial ports.

Please edit your Question and show the results of the commands I suggested.

Hello @waltinator, I have updated my question with the commands you've suggested. Are you not able to see them ?

As a test, what happens if you change your account's primary group to dialout and invoke the command?
